# How to notify my app when someone takes screenshot with the another app?

Tags: ios, screenshot, nsnotifications

Is there possibility to send notification to my app if someone takes screenshot when my app is in background?

Comment: Why do you want to know if someone took a screen shot?

Comment: Want to notify my app that new screenshot is in the photo gallery.

Comment: So what you really want to do is re-enumerate the asset library when you come back into the foreground then.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **NO**.
You can't get any update/event/listener/delegate when your app is in background while taking screenshot except the `Background Modes` provided by apple. 
Even in foreground also if you take a screen shot by combination of `Home Button + Power Button`, then also you won't be notified.

[image]

Comment: tnx for the answer .